# git archive remote with JGit

Tags: java, git, jgit

Can I perform a [`git archive`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive) from a remote repository without cloning through [JGit](https://eclipse.org/jgit/)? The idea is to improve my current clone and make it lighter by just bringing the files I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, JGit's archive command can only operate on a local repository. You will need to first (temporarily) clone the remote repository.

Comment: Should I report this behavior to JGit developers as it differs from common git archive?

Comment: Sure, you can file an enhancement request if you think this is a generally useful feature.